# Silverligth 4 [XAML] - giving letters in a text a background color/highligth

Tags: silverlight, xaml, text, expression-blend, markup

I am making some things in silverligth with marked up text in XAML.
Everything is going fine until i came up with this.

I am trying to give my text a background color but it says the property does not exist.
the property for a foreground does exist.

is there a way to still give my text parts a background color?

image in link:
http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/537/highligths.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those annoying Silverlight vs. WPF differences.  Neither TextBlock nor Run elements provide a Background property in Silverlight.  You need to wrap them in a Border:

```
<Border Background="Red">
  <TextBlock>Test please ignore</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Thus it's annoyingly involved to do precisely what you want, but possible.  If the text you want to display is not well known ahead of time, your best bet is to look at a third party RichTextBox control such as Telerik's RadRichTextBox.

Comment: thank you this was exactly what i was looking for. This is indeed a very anonying difference. Lets hope it will change in Silverligth v5

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me you did that with Textblock and Runs. I think the Run element can support foreground and background properties. I know you can twist the content to support both you just have to be clever about the controls inside the Textblock.

Comment: it doesnt matter what you think. Run doesnt have Background. This is why he asked.